# 'npm install' installs more than package.json dependencies

Tags: npm, dependencies, installation, package, package.json

Recently running 'npm install' in my terminal (in the root folder of my project, not the root folder of my computer) installs more than the packages in my package.json file. I guess it's install all my global packages but that's taking a while and taking some extra mb's...

My package.json file looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Test",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-buffer": "0.0.2",
    "gulp-compass": "^2.0.1",
    "gulp-jshint": "^1.8.5",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.2.4",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.0.1",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.1",
    "imagemin-pngquant": "^4.0.0",
    "jshint-stylish": "^1.0.0",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

What I get is this (this is only a quarter of the total folder) :

[Screenshot node_modules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nh6oH.png)

So my question: Can someone help me out how I can fix that only my package.json packages will be installed if I run npm install?

Comment: Are you using `npm@3`? This is part of the new deduplication implementation that landed with `npm@3`. You can find more information about it [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/how-npm-works/npm3).

Comment: I'm using npm version 3.10.3 . Thanks for the link with information, that seems to be it. Just checked the list with the primary dependencies via npm ls --depth=0 and I'm getting the packages of my package.json. Thanks!